# Are binomial distribution answers expressed as percentages?

Tags: statistics, binomial-coefficients

I have a question on an answer to a binomial distribution question. The chances of getting $100\%$ in a test is $8.881784197 \cdot 10^{-16}$. Is that actually a percentage? Making it $0.0000000000000008881784197\%$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The result you get from using the binomial distribution will be from $0$ to $1$. Although you can convert this to a percentage if you like, by multiplying by $100$ and appending a $\%$ sign, it does not "come out" as a percent.

If the question asks for the probability, you could write:

> $0.000000000000000888178$

If the question asks for the probability *as a percent*, you could write:

> $0.0000000000000888178\%$